# How to size nodes by weight and height using tidygraph with ggraph in R?

Tags: r, ggraph, tidygraph

I'm trying to size nodes of a tree by both the weight (which is equivalent to the nodes width in this context) and by it's height. To do this im using both `tidygraph`
and `ggraph`.

For example, if I create some data and turn it into a `tidygraph` object, I can then plot the tree using `ggraph`. If I just use the `weight` argument (in the `ggraph` call) I get a plot like the one below:

```
library(tidygraph)
library(ggraph)

# create some data
nodes <- tibble(
  var = c("x4", "x1", NA, NA, NA),
  size = c( 100, 65, 50,  15, 35)
)

edges <- tibble(
  from = c(1,2,2,1),
  to   = c(2,3,4,5)
)

# turn in tidygraph object
tg <- tbl_graph(nodes = nodes, edges = edges)

# plot using ggraph
ggraph(tg, "partition", weight = size) +
  geom_node_tile(aes(fill = var)) +
  geom_node_label(aes(label = size, color = var)) +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  theme_void()+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image: tree scaled by weight]

This scales the width of the trees nodes by the parameter `nodes$size`. However, if I try the same thing, except I replace the `weight` argument with `height`, that is:

```
# plot using ggraph
ggraph(tg, "partition", height = size) +
  geom_node_tile(aes(fill = var)) +
  geom_node_label(aes(label = size, color = var)) +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  theme_void()+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

I get a plot that omits the 1st node (as shown below) and the following error:

> Warning message: In hierarchy$height[edges[, node_col]] <- height :
> number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

[image: tree scaled by height]

I would like to somehow combine both the `weight` and `height` arguments into a single plot.

I tried experimenting by putting the `height` argument into the aesthetics for `geom_node_tile` like so:

```
ggraph(tg, "partition", weight = size) +
  geom_node_tile(aes(fill = var, height = size/100)) +
  geom_node_label(aes(label = size, color = var)) +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  theme_void()+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

but that leaves gaps between the nodes:
[image: tree scaled]

Is there a way to scale the nodes by both weight and height but still have a connected nodes, like in the example below (which I quickly made in powerpoint):
[image: tree proper]